# How to secure myself from the libpng buffer overflow in png_set_PLTE security bug?

Tags: security

As of today, there is a security bug affecting the libpng library. The severity with this is, that the library is used by huge amount of projects: browsers, music players, games, Linux Distro's.

Another factor is that, some use a modified libpng version, my question is, is Ubuntu affected by this? And, if so, how do I protect myself till they patch this bug?

Reference:

- [oss-security - CVE request: libpng buffer overflow in png_set_PLTE](http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2015/11/12/2)
- [Vulnerability Summary for CVE-2015-8126 - NVD - Detail](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2015-8126)

Answer (score 0):

Compile the fixed version, available [here](http://libpng.sourceforge.net/).

- Remove the vulnerable packacke with

  ```
  sudo dpkg -r --force-all libpng12-0
  ```

  Don't use `apt-get remove` or `apt-get purge`. With these commands, related programs and libraries would also be removed.
- Remove the development package

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove libpng12-dev
  ```

  Here is the usage of `apt-get remove` ok.
- Create a DEB package, e.g. with `checkinstall` and use `./configure --prefix=/usr`
- Enable the security channel (e.g. `wily-security` for Wily). Check more often for upgrades. The installed version will be overwritten, if a fixed version is available in the Ubuntu repositories

---

And yes, Ubuntu is currently also affected, the versions are

- Wily: `1.2.51-0ubuntu3`.
- Trusty: `1.2.50-1ubuntu2`
- Precise: `1.2.46-3ubuntu4`

Fixed versions are `1.6.19`, `1.5.24`, `1.4.17`, `1.2.54`, and `1.0.64`

---

To check, which applications depends on this library:

```
apt-cache rdepends libpng12-0
```

or to simulate the removal

```
sudo apt-get remove -s libpng12-0
```

Comment: Does Ubuntu use a modified version of libpng? If it does, does compiling libpng from source, break anything from my system? 14.04 64bit.

Comment: Whether Ubuntu uses its own version, I can not answer you.  A self-compiled version should not affect your system.

Comment: Gonna test this in a Virtual Machine, and it that goes well, I'll test it on my main machine. If it does not go well, then I'll post a report here.

Comment: Updated my answer and good luck.